# $11$ divides $10a + b$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $11$ divides $a − b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

### Problem

So, I am to show that $11$ divides $10a + b$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $11$ divides $a − b$.

---

### Attempt

This is a useful proposition given by the book:

---

**Proposition 12.** $11$ divides a $\Leftrightarrow$ $11$ divides the alternating sum of the digits of $a$.

*Proof.* Since $10 ≡ −1 \pmod{11}$, $10^e ≡ (−1)^n \pmod{11}$ for all $e$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
a&=&r_n10^n +r^{n−1}10^{n−1} +...+a_210^2 +a_110+a_0\\
&≡&a_n(−1)^n +a_{n−1}(−1)^{n−1} +...+a_2(−1)^2 +a_1(−1)+a_0 \pmod{11}.
\end{eqnarray}

---

So, I let "$a$" be $10a+b$, which means that $10a+b≡11k\pmod{11}$, or similarly that $\frac{10a+b-11k}{11}=n$, from some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Next, I write $10$ as $11-1$, which gives $\frac{11a-a+b-11k}{11}=\frac{11(a-k)+b-a}{11}=\frac{11(a-k)-(a-b)}{11}$. This being so we must then have that $(a-b)=11m$, for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ (zero works), but this would mean that $a≡b\pmod{11m}$, namely that $11m~|~a-b$. It is therefore quite plain that $11$ divides $10a+b$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $11$ divides $a-b$.

### Discussion

What I'd like to know is how I'm to use this to show that $11$ divides $232595$, another part of the same problem.

Comment: $10\equiv -1$ modulo $11$, so $10a+b\equiv -a+b$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $11$ divides $10a+b$, then
$$
10a+b=11k
$$
or
$$
b = 11k-10a
$$
so
$$
a-b=a-11k+10a=11(a-k)
$$
which means that $11$ divides $a-b$ as well, since $a,b,k$ are integers.

### Update

To prove in opposite direction you can do the same
$$
a-b=11k\\
b=a-11k\\
10a+b=10a+a-11k=11(a-k)
$$
or in other words, if $11$ divides $a-b$ it also divides $10a+b$.

So both directions are proved
$$
10a+b\equiv 0(\text{mod } 11) \Leftrightarrow a-b\equiv 0(\text{mod } 11)
$$

Comment: Very good. I like yours more.

Comment: However, how does this help to determine that number divides $11$?

Comment: @YosefQian I don't think I'm following your question.

Comment: Yes, the text asks to use this proof to show that number is divisible by $11$ . . .

Comment: @YosefQian Oh, that part. I overlooked it somehow. Anyway, Louis pretty much answered that.

Comment: Another way to do it: $232595$ is divisible by eleven $\iff$ $23259-5=23254$ is divisible by eleven $\iff$ $2325-4=2321$ is divisible by eleven $\iff$ $232-1=231$ is divisible by eleven $\iff$ $23-1=22$ is divisible by eleven $\iff$ $2-2=0$ is divisible by eleven. Since zero is divisible by any number and therefore by eleven, the original number is divisible by eleven.

Answer (score 1):

For your discussion: just use the theorem just proved.

$232595= 10 \cdot 23000 + 2595$

so it's enough to show that $11$ divides

$23000-2595= 20405$

now go on

$2000-405 = 1595$

$100-595 = -495$

$-40+95 = 55$

$5-5= 0$

Answer (score 1):

We have two cases to show double implications.(*To show converse is also true*)

Case $A$:

$11| 10a+b \implies11|21a+12b  \implies 11|22a+11b-(a-b) \implies11|a-b$

Case $B$:

$11|a-b \implies11|22a+11b-(a-b) \implies11|21a+12b \implies11|10a+b$

And thus, you have it. .:)

Answer (score 0):

$10a+b\equiv (10a+b)-11a \equiv -(a-b)$ is the most concise way of writing this argument.

You can apply this as follows, for the simple example 8492. I'll leave you to figure out your example.

Write it as $8490 + 2$. Then it is sufficient to consider $849-2=847$.

Write this as $840+7$. Then you get $84-7=77$. Then we are done.

This is equivalent to and slightly more fiddly than the more common alternating digit version.

Comment: Yes . . . Fiddly . . .

Answer (score 0):

10a+b ≡ -a+b (mod 11), so 11|10a+b iff -a+b ≡ 0 (mod 11) iff a-b ≡ 0 (mod 11) iff 11|a-b

Answer (score 0):

Number theory and modular arithmetic is great, but a little integer programming can be used to solve equations $11(xa+yb)+z(10a+b)=a-b$ and $11(xa+yb)+z(a-b)=10a+b$.

If $10a+b$ is divisible by $11$,$$\overbrace{11(11a+b)}^{\text{div by }11}-12\overbrace{(10a+b)}^{\text{div by }11}=a-b$$

If $a-b$ is divisible by $11$, $$\overbrace{11(-10a+11b)}^{\text{div by }11}+120\overbrace{(a-b)}^{\text{div by }11}=10a+b$$